# Node.js Memory Management

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management, node-modules

I experimented with Node.js v12.14.1.
When a module is loaded using require() the module is cached and loaded into memory.

a. How do we know the size of the memory footprint?
I used the below command to get an idea of how much memory is used. Is there a better approach?

```
 $ /usr/bin/time -l <cmd> 
        0.08 real         0.04 user         0.01 sys
  26722304  maximum resident set size     // Provides the max memory usage in bytes
         0  average shared memory size
         0  average unshared data size
         0  average unshared stack size
      6714  page reclaims
         0  page faults
         0  swaps
         0  block input operations
         0  block output operations
         0  messages sent
         0  messages received
         0  signals received
        94  voluntary context switches
       155  involuntary context switches
```

The below command, just starting the node REPL shows a maximum memory usage of 21 MB.

```
> $ /usr/bin/time -l node
```

When running a program that only loads a single module (ex: https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-templates) has a memory footprint of 76 MB.

```
var emailTemplates = require('email-templates');
```

```
$ /usr/bin/time -l node index.js
```

I am aware that the ignition interpreter along with TurboFan optimizes the code including bytecode into smaller more optimized bytecode and finally into machine code.

b. Does this apply to only warm/hot code that is frequently executed? Are the modules that are loaded optimized in any way?

My goal is to write JavaScript code that is fast, optimized and has a smaller memory footprint. I have read articles about writing good code (Ex - smaller named functions, not mixing data types of object properties, using promise libraries instead of native promises etc)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not to burst your bubble or anything, but if you really want low memory footprint for your app, node.js is probably not the right environment.  That's just not something it's very good at.  You could write something in C that would be tens of thousands of times smaller and give you direct control of all memory usage.

Comment: @jfriend00 I understand what you are talking about. But for several reasons I use Node.js for my backend.